# How to call a onclick function inside a Template literal in React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, template-literals

Please help me on writing an on click function in template literals in react js. By clicking the button in template literal I need to call another function in react js.

```
  addPopupToLayer = (surface, layer) => {
  const { surface_type: { name, color } } = surface;
  const customPopup = `
   <div class=${styles.tooltipHeader}>
      <h4>${surface.name}</h4>
      <button onclick=${()=> this.viewDetails(surface)}>View</button>
    </div>   
    <p>${name}</p>
  `;
  const customOptions = { className: styles.tooltip, width: '200' };
  const customlayer = layer.bindPopup(customPopup ,customOptions );

  customlayer.setStyle({
     fillColor: color,
     color,
     opacity: 1,
     fillOpacity: 0.48
  });
  return customlayer;
};


 viewDetails = (surface) => {
   console.log("View Details is Called")
  }
```

Comment: onclick={()=> ViewDetails(surface)} remove $ from start

Comment: also "onclick" should be "onClick"

Comment: @AmitChauhan Thanks for response when I removed $ from the start It is displaying ViewDetails(surface) on the button. It is considering the entire thing as a string

Comment: @shahnshah Thanks for responding I tried your suggestion but it is not working. I mean onClick event is not responding

Comment: @PavanKusunuri You need to remove $ from the start, that is right. But you have to add one $ for surface variable.

Comment: @PavanKusunuri  not binding the function sometimes creates this issue, have you tried binding it like this "this.ViewDetails = this.ViewDetails.bind(this)" in the constructor

Comment: @shahnshah I binded that function in constructor just as the same way you mentioned. still it is not working.

Comment: @PavanKusunuri Just out of curiosity shouldn't this function name this.ViewDetails(surface) start in with lowercase alpha?

Comment: @shahnshah it is a typo mistake, edited just now but I tried to call the function in the correct way

Answer (score 3):

remove $ symbol while calling the function, it will work

```
<button onclick={()=> ViewDetails(surface)}>View</button>
```

Comment: Is it possible to call a function using this keyword which I forgot to post just now edited

Comment: if the function in the same scope like if you have defined that function in same class, then you can use this.ViewDetails

Comment: both the functions are in same component but it still not calling the other function

Comment: Is there a way to convert my string literal code to jsx code so that I can bind that function

Answer (score 0):

```
const customPopup = 
`<div class=${styles.tooltipHeader}>
  <h4>${surface.name}</h4>
  <button onClick={()=> ViewDetails(${surface})}>View</button>
</div>   
<p>${name}</p>`;
```

If you are using surface variable, then it needs $ symbol within the template literal to indicate that surface is a variable and not part of the resulting string.

Comment: Is it possible to  call a function using this keyword which I forgot to post just now edited

Comment: Code only answers are rarely helpful. Please comment your code or expound on why this is the solution to the question.